# Multiple grid in Magento admin

Tags: magento-1.7

I am creating custom module in Magento. Please tell me How to add multiple grid in Magento admin? Or add some data after or before the grid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can in following steps

Lets say you have module called Mycompany_Mail. And you want to create two grids called
SentTray & RecvdTray

1) create a file Grid.php to create a class **Mycompany_Mail_Block_Adminhtml_SentTray_Grid** class under the folder Mycompany/Mail/Block/Adminhtml/SentTray/
and write the code to prepare columns inside it

2) create a file Grid.php to create a class **Mycompany_Mail_Block_Adminhtml_RecvdTray_Grid** class under the folder Mycompany/Mail/Block/Adminhtml/RecvdTray/
and write the code to prepare columns inside it

Note-1: do not create any other php file to initialize grid

Note-2: do not include blocks tag in your config.xml

3) Now, Lets create the controller file called MailController.php to create the 
**class Mycompany_Mail_Adminhtml_MailController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Actionunder** 
under the folder Mycompany/Mail/controllers/Adminhtml/

4) Lets create two actions one for accessing send tray and another for accessing recvd tray
like shown below

```
public function sendTrayAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mycompany_Mail_Block_Adminhtml_SentTray_Grid'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

public function recvdTrayAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mycompany_Mail_Block_Adminhtml_RecvdTray_Grid'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

5) Now, link the above two actions with menu item. Thats is it.

Answer (score 1):

You may add several grids to the page.Otherwise you will need to create some sort of compound collection in _prepareCollection method. In this case, you'd better create some new model which would be dealing with data.
Below is the structure you should go with to have multiple grids in one module.

```
- Namespace
     - Module
          - Block
             - Adminhtml
                 - Submodule1
                        - Grid.php
                 - Submodule2
                        - Grid.php
                 - Submodule3
                       - Grid.php
```

---