# Magento 1.9 custom admin grid load inside itself

Tags: magento, gridview, magento-1.9

[image: What my problem looks like]

I have 2 grids in the same module (and i need to keep them in the same module).
When i click on the top of the column the grid load itself inside itself.

Below is my code:
Myname_Blink_Adminhtml_BlinkController

```
public function keywordsAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu('blink/keywords');
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('Myname_Blink_Block_Adminhtml_Keywords_Grid'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

my block file : Myname_Blink_Block_Adminhtml_Keywords_Grid extends

```
class Myname_Blink_Block_Adminhtml_Keywords_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('keywords_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('keywords_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        //$this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }
```

As suggested to this post: [Multiple grid in Magento admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239144/multiple-grid-in-magento-admin)

I removed the files:
=>Myname_Blink_Block_Adminhtml_Keywords
=>app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\myname\blink.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something goes wrong with AJAX call.
Did you try this one:
http://davemacaulay.com/fix-issue-with-magento-adminhtml-grid-ajax-call-containing-the-whole-page/

```
public function keywordsAction()
{
    if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('Myname_Blink_Block_Adminhtml_Keywords_Grid')->toHtml());
        return $this;
    }

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Good luck!!!

Comment: Thanks ! it solved my problem. Have a nice day and thanks again !